How to uninstall PWA on Android Phone
I have installed a PWA on my Android phone and wanted to uninstall it by removing the icon from my home screen. However, this only removed the icon, but the app is still installed.
It should be possible to uninstall it by visiting chrome://apps, but this does not work on my mobile phone. Also, when I open the website in the browser, it automatically opens it up in full screen in app mode, so I can't uninstall it from there as well.
Seems to be like an ill designed system on mobile?

I was able to uninstall it not via browser, but by using the native phone search (the app was still listed).
